# How to know that which js file or function is applying inline css into my element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inline css in my element which i do not want. There is a lot of js in my website and i do not know from where this css is coming. 
Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to findout with the help of element ID.

Comment: You can solve such problems by re-applying CSS styles via JavaScriot after said inline styles have been applied- A document ready function towards the end of the HTML often does the trick, but in the long-haul, you'll want to single out the culprit javascript that applies those styles and modify it - it can be tricky, and often the real answer is to "burn it and start over"

Comment: There is not any id or class. I think it is coming through tag name. and its dynamic.

Comment: can you share what exactly the element is having js?

Comment: I would highly consider giving Kernel James the accepted answer. It's really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use [removeAtrr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) to remove all the inline style for that element:

```
$('#yourElementId').removeAttr("style");
```

After that, I'll set any style again through external css file or javascript if necessary.

Or if you want to override the inline styles, you can also try to use `!important` attribute in css.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most solid way to do it would be to use the browser's dev tools to run through the js one line at a time. This will show you the exact point in the code execution where the style is added. Here's a link demonstrating how to use breakpoints: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints

Otherwise, if you're confident the code will be jQuery functions, do a search for `.css(`. If it's possible the change is made without jQuery, search for `.style.`. Some other possibilities are `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, and `animate`. Once you find any of these, you can track what element they are being applied to to determine if they are relevant to the element you want to change.

Here are some selectors to look out for (vanilla JS and jQuery)

#### ClassName

```
document.getElementsByClassName('some-class');
$('.some-class');
```

#### ID

```
document.getElementById('some-id');
$('#some-id');
```

#### TagName

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tagNameHere');
$('tagNameHere');
```

#### QuerySelector

```
document.querySelector('cssSelectorHere');
document.querySelectorAll('cssSelectorHere');
$('cssSelectorHere');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problematic CSS is set with jQuery, you can hook into jQuery's `cssHooks` API to see when a particular CSS is being set. For example, if the problematic CSS is `"margin-right"` you can detect when it is being set and throw an exception so you can trace it through the browser's debugger:

```
var targetElement = document.getElement("checkme");

$(function() {

  $.cssHooks["marginRight"] = {
    set: function(node, value) {
      if(node == targetElement) {
        throw "stop that!";
      }
      else node.style.marginRight = value;
    }
  };

});
```